# UML:class model, user,role and relation with others class

Tags: uml, class-diagram, user-roles

I'm modeling a class model for a project and i'm a problem with member, statut (which is the role) and statut specialisation classes.
As you can see in the pic i have specialise statut class to show that a specific role is able to do an action. But i don't think my diagram is good cause if i do the database model from this diagram i get the "nom" field as foreign key but i want the "numMembre" field as foreign key for example in the information class.

[image: the class model]

Comment: Your "class model" it not really one. It's still a database model. Go back and start from a class model instead by removing all those ID fields.

Answer (score 0):

What you get is what you design ... "Secretary for information" is associated to Information, in DB Information gets a foreign key on "Secretary for information". That's normal.

If you want to have Numero member as foreign Key in Information, Membre has to be associated to Information.

But it is strange that you want to have Numero member as foreign Key in Information.

please see [orm](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)

Maybe this model is more linked to your concern: Two types of members (the third one seems like SG Section in your schema if not add it) and only secretary gets informations. And you will get memberId as foreign key in Inofrmation. I am not sure that's the best model but it can be one.

[image]

Comment: I want numMembre in information to know who posted the information! But i want to show here that it's only the member which have Secretary for informations as statut who can post informations

Comment: So your model seems good, but to know who posted an information, you sql request is a "bit" complex that's something like "select member from *** where member.membereid = statut.membereid and satutid = information.statutid

Comment: thanks for your help! i know the model seems good, but  i want to show for example that it's only the member who have Secretary for informations  as statut have the role to post informations. I don't know how to do it that's why i need help